# PHP counter excluding zeros

Tags: php, arrays, counter

In PHP I have an array that returns a set of values. I want to count the number of instances in the array excluding the zeros. Basically I'm creating an average total column in a table and if a person did not contribute then I don't want to count them. I have the total amount, just not the total count that contributes. Any help please?

Comment: `array_filter`, `count`

Comment: Michael, click "edit" under your question, paste your code, save the question. We need to see your code to figure out how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `count` and `array_filter` method.

`count` gives you the total number of elements in an array.

`array_filter` removes all elements whose value represents `false`(such as 0 empty string etc.) from an array;

Eg:

```
echo count(array_filter($your_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate the array and count the items that are not "zero".

```
$counter = 0;

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ( /* determine if $item is "not zero" */ ) {
        ++$counter;
    }
}

echo $counter;
```

That's all I can tell you based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a callback function to `array_filter` as the second parameter. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )
```

So you can do something like this:

```
function isNonZero(int $num){
    return $num !== 0;
}

count(array_filter([0,1,2,3,4], "isNonZero")); // => 4
```